# Ubuntu 12.04 Keyboard Shortcut without use of modifier key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Currently it seems you cannot enter keyboard shortcut combinations without the use of a modifier key. Is there any way to circumvent this, ie. a configuration file that I could manually enter these combinations into ?

Comment: Could you give us some examples of the shortcuts you're intending to implement?